# Placing script in to another page

Tags: php, json, if-statement

I have the following code placed in an php (Laravel) which shows my events placed on my site (I purchased the event script), I've tried placing the code into another php page but no events are showing!

Could someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction on how to place my events on another page please (if possible)?

```
@if(!empty($upcomming_events))
<section>
    <event-listing :events="{{ json_encode($upcomming_events, JSON_HEX_APOS) }}" 
                              :currency="{{ json_encode($currency, JSON_HEX_APOS) }}">
                            </event-listing>
</section>
@endif
```

Update, thank you Magnus figured it out with your help (what to look for).

Comment: Maybe there was no event data to show? It's unclear how you populate this variable or what the context it. More details required from you, and also please show how you've debugged it so far

Comment: That looks like blade syntax. Are you using Laravel? Always include what environment/cms/framework you're using, if any. Are you passing the `$upcomming_events` variable to the view from your controller? (I'm assuming it's Laravel). Show us the controller as well.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Yes the site is built in Laravel. I didn't create the script just playing around to list featured events on another page.

Comment: I've just updated my post to answer your kind replies. Thank you.

Comment: We only need to see the relevant controller method, not the complete class. Remove all code that's not relevant to the current page/view. We have no idea what controller method or view this is on so we don't have a clue where to start looking. The point is, for `$upcomming_events` to exist in the view, you need to pass it to the view from the controller method that loads it. That's basically as specific we can get, since we don't know how the library you're using works.

Comment: However, I don't see you passing (or even referencing) `$upcomming_events` anywhere in that controller.

Comment: Thank you Magnus for replying. "for $upcomming_events to exist in the view, you need to pass it to the view from the controller method that loads it.". Now that make sense. Thank you, I now know what to look for. Thank you very much (I'll delete the code).

Comment: You might want to read [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views) about views and view data.